# Syntax Issues When Creating a Login Page with Eclipse, JDBC, and MySQL

Tags: java, jsp

I am playing around with creating a login/registration page using Eclipse, JDBC, and MySQL. I am following an online tutorial and have been making good progress but I am stuck on one portion. The video states to use the code

`<input type="hidden" id="status" value="<% request.getAttribute("status") %>">`

But I get a syntax error message that says to use ;. I instead have done

`<input type="hidden" id="status" value="<% request.getAttribute("status"); %>">`

And although I am not getting any syntax errors, the code is not properly running. Could anyone please shed some insight? The video is from the beginning of 2022 so perhaps some stuff has been updated.

Comment: That should work, but note that it's a hidden <input> field, so you can't just see it. Also, this code is a giant security leak.

Comment: `<%=` if you want to get the value of the expression.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you just saved me so much time man, thank you so so much!!